# Programmatically search Youtube videos and return the first available one on a web page

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Good day!

Let's say I have a web page dedicated to a specific song by a specific author (eg "Imagine" by "John Lennon"). I would like to programmatically:

1. Search Youtube for the first n videos with "Imagine John Lennon"
2. Loop through these results to find a video which is available in the country where the user is located
3. Display the first video that matches the constraints on point 2. If no video matches them, then I won't display any video.

How can I do this? Is it better to do it with PHP or Ajax calls? I already checked some similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770395/search-youtube-and-display-results-on-my-website), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190620/how-do-i-check-if-a-youtube-video-is-blocked-restricted-deleted)) but as they are "old" I was wondering if there is a better method now.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a single call to the [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint, setting the 'q' and 'regionCode' parameters. Use any programming language you prefer.